# Access DBSCAN cluster in R

Tags: r, dbscan

With this code, I can understand I can plot the individual clusters.

```
library(fpc)
set.seed(665544)
n <- 600
x <- cbind(runif(10, 0, 10)+rnorm(n, sd=0.2), runif(10, 0, 10)+rnorm(n,sd=0.2))
ds <- dbscan(x, 0.2)
plot(x[ds$cluster %in% 1:3,])
```

For the above code, I am getting the following output,

```
ds

dbscan Pts=600 MinPts=5 eps=0.2
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
border 28  4  4  8  5  3  3  4  3  4  6  4
seed    0 50 53 51 52 51 54 54 54 53 51  1
total  28 54 57 59 57 54 57 58 57 57 57  5
```

I am getting all the 11 clusters.

If I want to display the data in a particular cluster, what R script I need to write for that.

Comment: Rather than expecting readers to know what package "dbscan" comes from or failing that expecting us to search for it, why not put in `library(whatever_package_it_comes_from)` at the top of your code block???

Comment: Updated. Its fpc library.

Comment: I got the answer by myself..

    pl[ds$cluster==1,]

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness:

As you found yourself you can plot a single cluster using

```
plot(ds$cluster = yourclusternum)
```

You can, however, do better by plotting all clusters, but in different colors:
If you also want to plot noise, do

```
plot(x, col=ds$cluster)
```

and if you do want to hide noise you just can do

```
plot(x[ds$cluster > 0,], col=ds$cluster[ds$cluster>0])
```